# Сериализация Десериализация ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть коллекция класса Text. Нужно при любом изменении в DataGrid провести сериализацию. Как это сделать.

````
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Text> Texts { get; set; } 
         
        public MainViewModel() 
        {

            Texts = new ObservableCollection<Text>() ;
            
        }
    } ```
````

Comment: У коллекции есть событие изменения (добавление/удаление), подписывайтесь, а дальше делайте что хотите. Также можете при добавлении/удалении подписаться на событие изменения (INPC) каждого объекта и тем самым уже определите изменения свойств самого объекта (если они вызывают INCP).

Answer (score 0):

Ответ есть на [Метаните](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.13.php)

Допустим, у нас будет следующий класс Person, который представляет пользователя:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Person(string name) => Name = name;
}
```

Для управления коллекцией объектов Person определим следующую программу:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
 
var people = new ObservableCollection<Person>() 
{ 
    new Person("Tom"), 
    new Person("Sam") 
};
// подписываемся на событие изменения коллекции
people.CollectionChanged += People_CollectionChanged;
 
people.Add(new Person("Bob"));  // добавляем новый элемент
 
people.RemoveAt(1);                 // удаляем элемент
people[0] = new Person("Eugene");   // заменяем элемент
 
Console.WriteLine("\nСписок пользователей:");
foreach (var person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
// обработчик изменения коллекции
void People_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add: // если добавление
            if(e.NewItems?[0] is Person newPerson)
                Console.WriteLine($"Добавлен новый объект: {newPerson.Name}");
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove: // если удаление
            if (e.OldItems?[0] is Person oldPerson)
                Console.WriteLine($"Удален объект: {oldPerson.Name}");
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace: // если замена
            if ((e.NewItems?[0] is Person replacingPerson)  && 
                (e.OldItems?[0] is Person replacedPerson))
                Console.WriteLine($"Объект {replacedPerson.Name} заменен объектом {replacingPerson.Name}");
            break;
    }
}
```